# iOS 8 Autolayout - Visual Format Language how to add constraint to superview's edge

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Can I pin my view to my superView's edge instead of its layout margin through VFL?
Can I be even flexible to toggle "Relative to margin" on myView as well?

**NO VFL (this is what I want to achieve with Visual Format Language):**

```
  var constraintLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

  var constraintRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
```

**VFL :**

```
 var constraintHorizontal = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[myView]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0),metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `"H:|[myView]|"` instead of `"H:|-[myView]-|"` to constrain to the edge.

Comment: Thx, can I toggle the "relative to margin" option as well on myView item somehow?

Comment: @luca You can update the `constant` property of the constraints, or just remove/add constraints.